# What is a Layered Graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

From wiki I got many details which really confused me.Can someone explain me with one example that How every directed cyclic graph can be converted to  directed acyclic graph using layering technique?I did not get how to know how many layers to make?Why to make "k" copies if k is the number of layers? If there is an edge between v1 and v2 such that they are  separated by a distance of more than one layer then how to connect? Please explain it with a proper example and in a simpler way.

Comment: Could you link to the Wiki?

Comment: Is it this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing

Comment: @YBerman   yeah right

Answer (score 2):

A [Layered Graph Drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing) is not a graph but a [graph drawing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing).

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a directed graph. Graphs are a set of things (vertices $V$) and connections between things (edges $E$). There isn't a definitive representation of a given graph on the plane. An example directed graph would be
$$G = (\{1,2,3\},\{(1,2), (2,3), (3,1)\}$$
Note this doesn't tell us how to lay it out.

It is sometimes useful to associate a graph with a function $f:V \to \mathbb R^2$ and a collection of functions $g_e:[0,1]\to \mathbb R^2$ for every $e \in E$ with the constraints that $g_e$ is continuous and $(g_e(0), g_w(1)) = e$. Essentially $f$ makes a dot for every vertex, and $g_e$ connects the start and end of $e$ with a curve.

This is called a graph embedding, which is a more formal way of talking about a graph drawing.

There are lots of interesting types of drawings:

- [drawings of planar graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph)
- [straight edge drawings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry%27s_theorem)
- [matchstick drawings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matchstick_graph)